# Array of booleans makes monstrosity

Tags: arrays, ada

I've inherited this bit of code and can't figure out what it does.  The definition looks simple enough:

```
result : BOOLEAN ;
LOOKUP_TABLE : array
  ( BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN,
    BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN ) of
  BOOLEAN := (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => (others =>
             (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => 
                TRUE ))))))))))))))));
```

In the body, it is used as follows:

```
result := LOOKUP_TABLE(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
                       FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE );
```

when dumping the lookup_table in GDB it creates a line that is over 500,000 characters long, the first little bit looks like this:

```
$1 = ((((((((((((((((true, true), (true, true)), ((true, true), (true, true))), (((true, true), (true, ...
```

Originally my question was going to be: How can a 16-boolean array be reduced to a single bool "result"?, but after looking at it in GDB, I have to ask "What is this thing???"

PS: After the call in the body, the LOOKUP_TABLE is still 500,000 characters, where every boolean field is TRUE...

Comment: Have you tried asking the guy who wrote this piece of code?

Comment: what a waste of resources! replace with a single array of 64K bools

Comment: Not neccessarily a waste. If the array is packed, each Boolean could take up 1 bit each.

Comment: @CapelliC: How is that a waste of resources? It contains exactly 65536 Boolean elements whether it's 1-dimensional or 16-dimensional. (A `pragma Pack` would likely be a good idea either way.)

Comment: I was sure I deleted my comment, before posting my answer... Anyway, the compiler *could* optimize it, as we can do by hand. For me, it's hard to believe it has dedicated logic for such declarations...

Comment: @Sven: original author long gone.  This code is around 15 years old.

Comment: At a meta level, this looks like a case of [feature creep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep) - It probably started as 1 or 2 dimensions and grew...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ada, an array isn't neccessarily indexed by an int starting from 0.
In this case, you have multi dimensional array with booleans as indexes.

When initializing an array, you have to specify the whole range of the array.

A one dimensional array would look like this:

`Lookup_Table : array(Boolean) of Boolean := (False..True => True);`

When dealing with larger arrays, it's inconvenient to specify all alternatives, hence the keyword `others`.
It means all alternatives not yet specified, so this is the same as above:

`Lookup_Table : array(Boolean) of Boolean := (others => True);`

This array now looks like this (1 being the dimension, and C being the content):

```
   1  |  C
 -----|-----
 False|True
 True |True
```

In a two-dimensional array, this would be:

`Lookup_Table : array(Boolean, Boolean) of Boolean := (others => (others => True));`

```
   1  |  2  |  C
 -----|-----|-----
 False|False|True
 False|True |True
 True |False|True
 True |True |True
```

In your case it's 16 dimensions.

You can read more about Ada array [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/array)

Comment: Thank you.  Sounds awful.  Not sure if that was intended by the original author.  But how is "result" determined?  I haven't found any documentation on how an array of bool can be reduced to a single bool.  Is it an OR clause or an AND clause?

Comment: It's not, `others` will put the same value in each place of the array.
So instead of saying `(True, True)` you can say `(others => True)`

Comment: Right -- and my "reducing" question is stupid, because there's exactly one boolean at the intersection of the 16 indexes, and that's what result becomes.

Comment: Conceptually `others` is a loop, which is more intuitive when the value is the result of a function, and in your case, that's exactly what you have; enumerators, like True and False, are actually parameterless functions. (Although with Boolean, I would think the compiler is allowed to make some optimizations)

Answer (score 7):

That's not a 16-boolean array. It's a 16-*dimensional* array, with each dimension ranging from `false` to `true`, so it has 2<sup>16</sup>, or 65536, elements.

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this, and the table had relatively few values of interest I'd probably use a Map with a multi-part key:

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps;

package Bool_16_Mapping is

   Key_Arity : constant := 16;

   type Key_Range is range 1 .. Key_Arity;

   type Bool_16_Keys is array (Key_Range) of Boolean;

   package Bool_16_Array_Management is
     new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps
       (Bool_16_Keys, Boolean);

end Bool_16_Mapping;
```

The values of interest then get inserted into the map. During execution, use a short-circuit *Contains() and then Element()*, or write a little function to do it. Here's an example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Bool_16_Mapping;

procedure Bool_16_Map_Test is

   Lookup_Table : Bool_16_Mapping.Bool_16_Array_Management.Map;

   Working_Key : Bool_16_Mapping.Bool_16_Keys := (others => False);

   function Get_Result (P1,   P2,  P3,  P4,
                        P5,   P6,  P7,  P8,
                        P9,  P10, P11, P12,
                        P13, P14, P15, P16 : Boolean) return Boolean is
      Key : Bool_16_Mapping.Bool_16_Keys := 
        (P1,  P2,  P3,  P4,  P5,  P6,  P7,  P8,
         P9, P10, P11, P12, P13, P14, P15, P16);
      Result : Boolean := False;
   begin
      if Lookup_Table.Contains(Key) then
         Result := Lookup_Table.Element(Key);
      end if;
      return Result;
   end Get_Result;

   Lookup_Result : Boolean;

   use type Bool_16_Mapping.Key_Range;

begin
   -- Initialize the table with some values
   for K in Bool_16_Mapping.Key_Range loop
      Working_Key (K) := True;
      Lookup_Table.Insert(Working_Key, K mod 2 = 0);
   end loop;

   Lookup_Result := Get_Result
     (True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
      False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False);
   Put_Line("#1: " & Boolean'Image(Lookup_Result));

   Lookup_Result := Get_Result
     (True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False,
      False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False);
   Put_Line("#2: " & Boolean'Image(Lookup_Result));

   Lookup_Result := Get_Result
     (False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
      False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False);
   Put_Line("#3: " & Boolean'Image(Lookup_Result));

end Bool_16_Map_Test;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm still wrapping my head around why the OA thought he needed a 16-dimensional array.  But since the code works, the desire to change is quite low...

Comment: This would be fine if the truth table was static, I'm not so sure it'd be a good idea if it was dynamic. I had a similar example where about 10 input conditions had to be evaluated every 10 milliseconds or so to decide whether to continue with a missile launch, and the array design was a very close match to the specification as produced by the system engineer ... I did try to make it more legible than @erict's sample, though!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff usually represent flags that indicates some permissions. ie.

IsAdmin
CanEdit
CanInsert
CanDelete

So if someone is an admin and can edit but no insert nor delete it will be: 1100. Maybe this big array means the same.

Answer (score 0):

That was chosen probably because the values are *sparse*. I think you could replace with a single array of 64K bools, that is an array of 8K bytes (8192 unsigned chars). Set initially to 0, and set to 1 each used entry, bit oring the keys.